# Using a NOT LIKE conditional when filtering DataTables

Tags: jquery, datatable

Is it possible to use a NOT LIKE conditional when filtering DataTable?

The DataTable is not populated via an ajax call, it is just populated from a simple query looped over in the page.

I want to be able to enter something like this: "W-2%" in the search box and only show items that do not start with "W-2".

So basically I am doing this: where name NOT LIKE 'W-2%'

DataTable Js

```
    $('#inventoryLocationTable').DataTable( {
        "iDisplayLength": 20,
        "order": [[ 1, "asc" ]],
        "aLengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, 100, 500, 1000], ["10 Per Page", "25 Per Page", "50 Per Page", "100 Per Page", "500 Per Page", "1000 Per Page"]]
    });
```

Is this possible? Thanks.

Comment: sure it's possible, see `filter()` docs  https://datatables.net/reference/api/filter%28%29

Answer (score 3):

You could use fnFilter as described in https://datatables.net/api or also you could build you own custom filter (explained in http://datatables.net/development/filtering)

If you need to match all results except the ones starting with *W-2*, maybe you could only use fnFilter and build a regex.

In this case it would be:

```
$('#inventoryLocationTable').dataTable().fnFilter("^(.(?!W-2))*$", null, true, false);
```

I build a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qweo7bkn/1/) to test it, it forces the filter after loading the table (check that rows containing W-2% doesn't appear).